# Java 11 package is declared in module which does not export it

Tags: java, javafx

I have created two modular programs. One is JavaFX modular project that contains `module-info.java` like:

```
module checker {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires TextInputProgram; // Btw, IDEA shows me here "Ambiguous module reference"
    exports sample;
    opens sample;
}
```

Another Maven project that contains `module-info.java` like:

```
module TextInputProgram {
    requires selenium.api;
    requires selenium.chrome.driver;
}
```

So, I added modular maven project as external jar into JavaFX (via Project Structure in libs and in module-info via `requires` I specified jar). Also I added variable that contains external jar for compilation (in addition to `PATH_TO_FX` and `PATH_TO_FX_MODS`):

```
set EXTERNAL_JAR="...\out\artifacts\TextInputProgram_jar"
```

But when I'm trying to compile the project via command:

```
dir /s /b src\*.java > sources.txt & javac --module-path %EXTERNAL_JAR%;%PATH_TO_FX% -d mods/checker @sources.txt & del sources.txt
```

following [this tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular)

I'm getting from JavaFX project class the error:

```
\src\sample\Controller.java:9: error: package project is not visible
import project.SeleniumProgram;
       ^
  (package project is declared in module TextInputProgram, which does not export it)
1 error

Package is declared in module which does not export it
```

`import project.SeleniumProgram` I imported in JavaFX project to use classes from external jar.

**Updated:**

If I add `exports project;` inside module-info.java of maven project then I see the error in JavaFX module-info.java:

[image]
If I delete `requires TextInputProgram;` then I have another error from import:

[image]

Am I missing something here? I'm trying to get executable Jar of these two programs.

Comment: Adding the `TextInputProgram` module to your JavaFX project is not enough, if all the public packages of the module are not opened or exported. You will need to add something like `exports project`, so any module can access this package, or `exports project to checker` if you want to give access only to a given module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, José Pereda. yes,  tried to use the command `exports project` in module-info inside maven project,  but when I'm opening JavaFx project module-info where I'm using this external jar I see the error: module reads package from both 'TextInputProgram' and 'TextInputProgram'. When I'm deleting `requires TextInputProgram;` then I don't see the issue, but I need it because of import that requires it.

Comment: If you use `opens project to checker` instead of `exports`, does it fix the error?

Comment: It looks like you have two different versions of the same TextInputProgram jar? You can verify that in the External Libraries.

Comment: To clarify:
I have two different projects. And if I use `opens project to checker;` inside maven project then IDEA says me that module checker not found (emphasize me via yellow marker).In JavaFX module I'm still having: `ambiguous module reference`. In External libs I have only one version TextInputProgram. Do I need to combine two projects? Maybe it would be better as one maven project with multiple modules?

Comment: But JavaFX includes jar of maven project.

Comment: It’s really hard to say without having a look at your project. Is it possible that you share it (for instance in GitHub,  removing whatever is not necessary to reproduce the issue)?

Comment: Yes, I can if it helps. I can send link in private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed throughout the comments, there are a few possible issues here:

- Module definition
- Local jars and dependencies

Based on the modular projects posted, I'll create a small demo multi-modular project to explain both problems.

#### Maven multi-modular project

Using your IDE, create a Maven project, then add two modules, `TextInputProgram` and `checker`, like:

**Parent pom**

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>TextInputProgram</module>
    <module>checker</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

**TextInputProgram pom**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>TextInputProgram</artifactId>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Module-info.java**

```
module TextInputProgram {
    requires selenium.api;
    requires selenium.chrome.driver;

    exports project to checker;
}
```

**Checker pom**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>testMods</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>checker</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>TextInputProgram</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Module-info.java**

```
module checker {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires TextInputProgram;

    opens sample to javafx.fxml;

    exports sample;
}
```

(Code of both modules is irrelevant at this point).

#### Solutions included

Now note that you have to add this in the `TextInputProgram` module descriptor:

```
exports project to checker;
```

if you want to let `checker` module to access `TextInputProgram`'s `project` package.

This will solve this error:

> package project is declared in module TextInputProgram, which does not export it

Also, note that I've included this dependency in the `checker` project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>TextInputProgram</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Even having two modules, under the same parent, you need to include the dependency from one module to the other. Otherwise this will fail (module not found):

```
requires TextInputProgram;
```

You can run `mvn clean install` in the `TextInputProgram` module, to install `org.openjfx:TextInputProgram:1.0-SNAPSHOT` in your local repository `.m2`.

Then you can run `mvn clean javafx:run` int the `checker module`, to run the GUI project.

It is worth mentioning that it is not a good idea to combine both maven dependencies with jar files. If you end up using both, you will get this error:

> Module 'checker' reads 'project' from both 'TextInputProgram' and 'TextInputProgram'

This message means that there are two modules in the module path with the exact same name, one the maven dependency, the other one, the jar artifact.

In order to distribute your project and modules, it is better to use the maven approach, and avoid having jar files in lib folders. Later on your modules will be published as separated artifacts, and you won't need to modify your pom files (other than to update the version numbers).